# Template suggestions are shows, even though all debug settings are off

Tags: 10

We recently upgrade our Drupal 9 site to Drupal 10. The TWIG debug information now outputs all the template suggestions.

We have all debug setting off (FALSE) in the the *services.yml* file.

Of course, Drupal 10 has the new UI interface to control the debug settings, but there are already off by default. I've tried enabling, disabling, and clearing caches, but the debug information is still output on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check

```
drush ev "var_dump(\Drupal::getContainer()->getParameter('twig.config'));"
```

If the debug value is TRUE, any *services.yml file could have set the container parameter.

Then check all hits except the scaffold default file:

```
grep -r 'twig.config:' --include *.yml
```

If not a YAML file it's possible a module sets the array in PHP `setParameter('twig.config', $config)`.

Comment: Awesome! It was a development.services.yml file - not sure where it came from or when but removing it has resolved the issue. Thank you!